# use a switch statment to size textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have the below code that I need to set the MaxLength of a textbox in my application. The code seems ok but its not working. Can anyone see what is the problem.

```
        private void cbType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db.MDF;Integrated Security=True";

        string Query = "select * from RePriorities where Priority='" + cbType.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {

            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            string sType = myReader.ToString();

            switch (sType)

            {
                case "Low": txtDesc.MaxLength = 5; break;
                case "Medium": txtDesc.MaxLength = 10; break;
                case "High": txtDesc.MaxLength = 1; break;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 


    }
```

Comment: Describe "but its not working". It is not clear.

Comment: Output sType into txtDesc, might help

Comment: Debug the code. What is the value of sType at the point of the switch?

Comment: You realise `MaxLength` is the text length not the size of the textbox right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you open a SqlDataReader you need to call the Read method to place the internal record pointer to the first record. Only after that you could extract values from the reader

```
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        if(myReader.Read())
        {
            string sType = myReader["name_of_field"].ToString();
            switch (sType)
            {
                case "Low": txtDesc.MaxLength = 5; break;
                case "Medium": txtDesc.MaxLength = 10; break;
               case "High": txtDesc.MaxLength = 1; break;
            }
        }
```

also you need to tell the reader the name (or index) of the field that you want to read back.

Said that let me point you to a big problem in your code. It is the string concatenation that you make at the beginning of the method to prepare the command text. You should never use string concatenation but always a parameterized query

```
    string constring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
    string Query = "select * from RePriorities where Priority=@priority";
    using(SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring))
    using(SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", cbType.SelectedItem.ToString());

        ......

        // the rest of your code
    }
```

**EDIT** I forgot to add an explanation for the suggestion to avoid string concatenation. Here a sample article from [MSDN on Sql Injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx), also an internet search will explain the problems that arise with string concatenation in sql commands